# asp.net - Trying to insert only one cell of data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

Im Passing a querystring to my load page (ID)
and then trying to SELECT a column of that row (Status) so its eventually only one cell.

My goal is to take some Label(not a textbox) in the page that has some text, and place it in the "Status" cell.

this is my code :

> this.conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
>               conn.Open();
>               string idIndex = Request.QueryString["ID"];
>               string sqlquery1 = "INSERT INTO Movies (Status) VALUES (@Status)";
>               string sqlquery2 = "SELECT Status FROM Movies WHERE ID=" + idIndex;

```
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery2, conn);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery2, conn);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        string data = "";

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            data = dataRow["Status"].ToString();
        }

        if (data == "")
        {
            string username = UserNameOrGuest.Text;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery1, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", username);
            ErrorLabel.Text = "Movie rental succeeded!";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        else
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "The movie is already rented by somebody else.";
        }
    }
```

And I get an exception :

" Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Ganere', table 'Movie.dbo.Movies'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

("Ganere" its another column from the table, that I dont want it to pass.)

THanks for the helpers!

Comment: Sounds like your table requires more than just the "Status" field.  You either need to set defaults for those fields or populate those fields on insert.

Comment: when you insert - you create a new row.
This row will need default in the columns that is NOT inserted - some constraints prevents this. Insert needs to have all the relevant columns
sure you do not need a UPDATE ?

Comment: Thanks, it was the update thingy :)

Comment: another thing I come across with this , that whan I make an update, its updating in all the cells in the Status (all the rows).
how can I manuover that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really how a table works.  When inserting a record, that record needs to meet the data integrity criteria of the table.  In this particular case, it sounds like the table has a required column.  (It may even have more required columns and that's just the first one it encountered in your query.)

Your options at this point are:

1. Insert a value into that column as well, either a dummy/default value or something real.
2. Alter the table to allow `null` in that column.
3. Alter the table to have a default value for that column when one isn't supplied.

Comment: @thormayer - And then modify your .net code to validate the information you get from the QueryString to avoid SQL Injection attacks!  [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it was the "Update" thingy.

Comment: another thing I come across with this , that whan I make an update, its updating in all the cells in the Status (all the rows). how can I manuover that ?

Comment: @thormayer: Your `UPDATE` needs a `WHERE` clause to specify the exact row(s) that should be updated.  Without such a clause, all rows are updated.

Comment: @thormayer: No problem, glad we could help :)